# insert multiselect field type as an array in Grocery Crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

currently i use multiselect field type to selecting from my table, but my concern is the multiselect only inserted in one record, meanwhile what i'm expecting is i can inserted 3 rows when the multiselect reach a 3 selected items.

PFB my Code.

```
$car_identification_no = array();
            foreach ($this->db->get_where('drv_user')->result() 
            as $row) {
                $car_identification_no[$row->drv_user_id] = $row->car_identification_no;
            }

->field_type('car_identification_no','multiselect',$car_identification_no)
```

The result for that record it's like below images
[image: On the red Color]

I want to insert that 0,1,3 as an record like below

```
ads_car_aq_id|ads_advertisement_id|car_identification_no|superspring_id|description

9 |2|0|123456
10|2|1|123456
11|2|3|123456
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php 
  // if youur value is "0,1,3"
  $val="0,1,3";
  $array=explode(",",$val);
  $insert=array();
  foreach($array as $k=>$v)
  { 
    $tmp=array(
      "ads_car_aq_id"=>9,
      "ads_advertisement_id"=>2,
      "car_identification_no"=>$v,
      "superspring_id"=>123456,
      "description"=>""
      );
   array_push($insert,$tmp);
  }
// your table name is "drv_user"
  $this->db->insert_batch('drv_user',$insert);
?>
```

Comment: i knew the insert_batch, but my problem currently i use the grocery_crud for the crud operations...